# iOS: is it allowed to paint outside the bounds

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

If clipToBounds = YES then you can draw all you want, but you only can paint inside the bounds. If it is set to NO then painting outside the bounds is possible, but is it allowed?

The reason that I'm asking is because iOS uses the concept where the environment takes care of making sure the correct parts of the screen are (re)painted (e.g. setNeedsDisplay). If I draw outside my bounds, will it goof up?

I have tried it, and it seems to work, but?

Comment: Based on the answers, it seems that you can, but why would you want to? Drawing things that are not being shown is a waste of resources.

Comment: You did not read my first sentense right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evgen is right and it is clearly documented in "View Programming Guide for iOS". You will not be able to handle events from outside of the bound though.

Comment: Quoted from the manual: By default, a view’s frame is not clipped to its superview’s frame. Thus, **any subviews that lie outside of their superview’s frame are rendered in their entirety**. You can change this behavior, though, by setting the superview’s clipsToBounds property to YES. Regardless of whether or not subviews are clipped visually, **touch events always respect the bounds rectangle of the target view’s superview**. In other words, touch events occurring in a part of a view that lies outside of its superview’s bounds rectangle are not delivered to that view.

Comment: You are right I misunderstood your question, sorry. I'm ashamed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your app gets rejected by Apple, if that's what you mean. After all it's just making use of a public and documented API. But be prepared for strange effects as this way the correct drawing order cannot be guaranteed any more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's work and there is nothing wrong with using this property. Your objects will be repainted as necessary.

Comment: it would be great to have some kind of supporting information stating that painting outside the bounds is allowed / will not cause problems